# How to zip two arrays without truncating to the shortest array?

Tags: python, arrays

im trying to write a script in python that gives me each item in array A and what it corresponds in array B

let's say array A are Customers 
and array B are rooms

```
A = 'Customer 1','Customer 2','Customer 3','Customer 4'
B = 'room 1','room 2','room 3','room 4'

for Customers,rooms in zip(A,B):
    print Customers +' is in '+ rooms
```

and the output is:

```
Customer 1 is in room 1
Customer 2 is in room 2
Customer 3 is in room 3
Customer 4 is in room 4
```

now what if we have only 3 rooms in array B 
the output well ignore Customer 4

```
Customer 1 is in room 1   
Customer 2 is in room 2
Customer 3 is in room 3
```

my quistion is how to make it write for me `all rooms are reserved` if A>b

```
Customer 1 is in room 1
Customer 2 is in room 2
Customer 3 is in room 3
customer 4 all rooms are reserved
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) over `zip` to fill in the shorter list with `None` values and update your logic like below:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

for customer, room in izip_longest(A, B):
    if room:
        print customer + ' is in ' + room
    else:
        print customer + ' all rooms are reserved'
```

Comment: Or `map` built-in function and passing `None` as the first argument under (Python 2.X).

Comment: thank you man that help a lot you save the day

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% I understood what you meant by

> how to make it write for me all rooms are reserved if A>b

but my inference is you want some sort of default value if you A>B.  For this you can use `itertools.zip_longest`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

A = 'Customer 1','Customer 2','Customer 3','Customer 4'
B = 'room 1','room 2','room 3','room 4', 'room 5', 'room 6'

for Customer, rooms in zip_longest(A, B, fillvalue='all rooms reserved'):
    print(Customer, rooms)
```

If however you need to simply display `all rooms reserved` when A>B, then you you would just have an `if` statement and print...but that's too easy.

Comment: that works tow thank you